VSCode on Linux: Inserting an absolute path copied from Nautilus
Scenario:
copy the path by selecting an item from the Nautilus file manager and press Ctrl+C. Insert the path in some file in VSCode.
Result:
automatic insertion of a path relative to the opened workspace, with a UI button to
switch to the absolute path.
Is it possible to insert absolute paths by default, instead of relative paths? I haven't found such an option in the Settings.
